# Angular: E2E Test via login page

Tags: javascript, angular, express, protractor, e2e-testing

I have an Angular application using an Express.js backend. It features a default address pathway to a login page `/avior/login`. I need to write an E2E Test for the whole application and I just started writing the first test part which is supposed to recognize the login page and login itself and then check whether the redirect was successful. I have wrote this error-prone code so far:

```js
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import { browser, logging, element } from 'protractor';
import { async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick,
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {AppComponent} from '../../src/app/app.component'

let comp:     AppComponent;
let fixture:  ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
let page:     AppPage;
let router:   Router;
let location: SpyLocation;
let username: 'Test';
let password: 'testtest';
let usernameInput: element(by.css('#inputUser'));
let passwordInput: element(by.css('#inputPassword'));
let loginButton: element(by.css('#loginSubmit'));

describe('Avior App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('should navigate to "/avior/login" immediately', fakeAsync(() => {
    createComponent();
    tick(); // wait for async data to arrive
    expect(location.path()).toEqual('/avior/login', 'after initialNavigation()');
    expectElementOf(DashboardComponent);
  }));

  it('should display Login message in the header', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect(page.getTitleText()).toEqual('Anmeldung');
  });

  it('there should be username and password login fields', () => {
  // how to check?
  });

  it('login using false credentials should make you stay put and throw an error', () => {
  // how to?
  });

  it('login using Test:testtset (=successful credentials => successful login) should redirect to /avior/dashboard', () => {
  // how to?
  });


  afterEach(async () => {
    // Assert that there are no errors emitted from the browser
    const logs = await browser.manage().logs().get(logging.Type.BROWSER);
    expect(logs).not.toContain(jasmine.objectContaining({
      level: logging.Level.SEVERE,
    } as logging.Entry));
  });
});


function createComponent() {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  comp = fixture.componentInstance;

  const injector = fixture.debugElement.injector;
  location = injector.get(Location) as SpyLocation;
  router = injector.get(Router);
  router.initialNavigation();
  spyOn(injector.get(TwainService), 'getQuote')
    // fake fast async observable
    .and.returnValue(asyncData('Test Quote'));
  advance();

  page = new Page();
}

function loginFn() { 

  usernameInput.sendKeys(username);
  passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
  loginButton.click();
};
```

How to fix this code?

**UPDATE**

I tried simplifying my code to only include routing tests so far and I get new errors thrown out.
My new code is the following:

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import { browser, logging, element } from 'protractor';
import { async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick,
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {AppComponent} from '../../src/app/app.component'
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {RouterTestingModule} from "@angular/router/testing";
import {Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import { AviorComponent } from '../../src/app/avior/avior.component';

import { DashboardComponent } from '../../src/app/avior/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from '../../src/app/avior/profile/profile.component';
import { SettingsComponent } from '../../src/app/avior/settings/settings.component';
import { LoginComponent } from '../../src/app/avior/login/login.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from '../../src/app/avior/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { InfoComponent } from '../../src/app/avior/info/info.component';
import { UsersComponent } from '../../src/app/avior/users/users.component';
import { MandatorsComponent } from '../../src/app/avior/mandators/mandators.component';
import { SystemComponent } from '../../src/app/avior/system/system.component';
import { WorkflowsComponent } from '../../src/app/avior/workflows/workflows.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from '../../src/app/avior/messages/messages.component';

import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
/* let comp:     AppComponent;
let fixture:  ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
let page:     AppPage;
let router:   Router;
let location: SpyLocation;
let username: 'Chad';
let password: 'chadchad';
let usernameInput: element(by.css('#inputUser'));
let passwordInput: element(by.css('#inputPassword'));
let loginButton: element(by.css('#loginSubmit')); */

const aviorRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '', component: AviorComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '', component: ProfileComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent,
      data: {title: 'Dashboard'},
    },
    {
      path: 'login', component: LoginComponent,
      data: {title: 'Login'},
    },
    {
      path: 'logout', component: LoginComponent,
      data: {title: 'Login'},
    },
    {
      path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent,
      data: {title: 'Profil'},
    },
    {
      path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent,
      data: {title: 'Einstellungen'},
    },
    {
      path: 'info', component: InfoComponent,
      data: {title: 'Info'},
    },
    {
      path: 'users', component: UsersComponent,
      data: {title: 'Benutzer'},
    },
    {
      path: 'workflows', component: WorkflowsComponent,
      data: {title: 'Workflows'},
    },
    {
      path: 'system', component: SystemComponent,
      data: {title: 'System'},
    },
    {
      path: 'mandators', component: MandatorsComponent,
      data: {title: 'Mandanten'}
    },
    {
      path: 'messages', component: MessagesComponent,
      data: {title: 'Nachrichten'}
    },
    {
      path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent,
      data: {title: 'Page not found'},
    }
   ]
}];

describe('Avior App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
       platformBrowserDynamicTesting())
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(aviorRoutes)],
      declarations: [
        DashboardComponent,
        ProfileComponent,
        SettingsComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent,
        InfoComponent,
        UsersComponent,
        MandatorsComponent,
        SystemComponent,
        WorkflowsComponent,
        MessagesComponent
    ]
   });
    page = new AppPage();

    this.router = TestBed.get(Router);
    location = TestBed.get(Location);

    this.fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    this.router.initialNavigation();
  });

/*   it('should navigate to "/avior/login" immediately', fakeAsync(() => {
    createComponent();
    tick(); // wait for async data to arrive
    expect(location.path()).toEqual('/avior/login', 'after initialNavigation()');
    expectElementOf(DashboardComponent);
  })); */

  it('navigate to "" redirects you to /avior/login', fakeAsync(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['']);
      tick();
      expect(location.path()).toBe('/avior/login');
  }));

  it('navigate to "dashboard" takes you to /dashboard', fakeAsync(() => {
       this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
       tick();
       expect(location.path()).toBe('avior/dashboard');
  }));


  it('should display Anmeldung message in the header', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect(page.getTitleText()).toEqual('Anmeldung');
  });

  it('there should be username and password login fields', () => {

  });

  it('login using false credentials should make you stay put and throw an error', () => {

  });

  it('login using Chad:chadchad should redirect to /avior/dashboard', () => {

  });



  afterEach(async () => {
    // Assert that there are no errors emitted from the browser
    const logs = await browser.manage().logs().get(logging.Type.BROWSER);
    expect(logs).not.toContain(jasmine.objectContaining({
      level: logging.Level.SEVERE,
    } as logging.Entry));
  });
});


/* function createComponent() {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  comp = fixture.componentInstance;

  const injector = fixture.debugElement.injector;
  location = injector.get(Location) as SpyLocation;
  router = injector.get(Router);
  router.initialNavigation();
  spyOn(injector.get(TwainService), 'getQuote')
    // fake fast async observable
    .and.returnValue(asyncData('Test Quote'));
  advance();

  page = new Page();
}

function loginFn(username, password) {
  usernameInput.sendKeys(username);
  passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
  loginButton.click();
};
 */
```

The errors get thrown out during `ng e2e` runtime:
`- Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?). - Failed: Cannot read property 'assertPresent' of null`

Comment: What specifically is the issue you are encountering?

Comment: @DublinDev I get errors thrown out. I also changed my code to only include routing tests and now I'm getting `- Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?).
  - Failed: Cannot read property 'assertPresent' of null` errors during runtime

Comment: Also it would be brilliant if someone at least gave me some idea how to write the remaining tests that are commented with how to